# Why is SELECT..PROCEDURE a MySQL syntax error?

Tags: mysql, select, procedure

I want to run a MySQL query and then process all the result sets.  The MySQL
5.7 documentation says that the way to do is to use SELECT ... PROCEDURE
stored_procedure_name(parameters).  I created a stored procedure that does what I want without any problems.  I used it in a SELECT ... PROCEDURE query and got this syntax error:

ComposeStatement (identifier) is not valid at this position

(where ComposeStatement is the name of my stored procedure).  I checked I have the proper number of parameters and they are of the proper type.  Using a
different procedure gives the same error (with the obvious change in name).

The documentation shows an example of this syntax using a procedure called
ANALYSE (which I understand from another post is now deprecated, but I really don't care about using ANALYSE specifically).  When I tried the example I get the same error, with ANALYSE as the identifier.  The errors I'm getting are 
not in the procedures themselves, which is why many earlier posts don't apply.

Any suggestions?  The SELECT..PROCEDURE construct sounds like it's exactly
what I need.

Comment: I can't figure out what you're talking about. Show your code. And if you're referring to something in the documentation, give a link to the documentation page.

Comment: @Barmar https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select.html and https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/procedure-analyse.html

Comment: What documentation? I've never known MySQL to support SELECTing from stored procedure results.

Comment: Each client language has a way to handle the multiple resultsets that come out of Stored Procedure.

Answer (score 4):

The MySQL feature @LarryGriffith references has nothing to do with stored procedures.

It's related to this deprecated feature: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/procedure-analyse.html

```
SELECT col1, col2 FROM table1 PROCEDURE ANALYSE(10, 2000);
```

This use of the `PROCEDURE` query modifier is like putting a filter function on the result set from a query. It's analogous to a pipeline in the shell:

```
ls | grep myfile
```

The thing is, the "procedure" you use (`ANALYSE()` in the example) **is not a stored procedure** of the type you can write with `CREATE PROCEDURE`.

You would have to code the filtering function in C++ and compile it with the MySQL source.

The `ANALYZE()` example was originally meant as a proof of concept or example that developers could follow if they wanted to develop their own query filters. But I've never heard of anyone who actually did create a query filter of their own.

Last year it was announced that the `SELECT ... PROCEDURE ANALYZE()` feature was intended to be deprecated in MySQL 8.  http://www.tocker.ca/2015/06/29/plan-to-deprecate-procedure-analyse.html

If you need to post-filter a query result, it's far easier to write a script (in Python or whatever your favorite language is), which fetches the raw data from the query result, and then does whatever you need to do with it.

Comment: Thanks for all the responses.  hjpotter kindly provided the links to the documentation; I had thought (obviously incorrectly) that the index located

Comment: Sorry, I accidentally hit RETURN and closed my previous comment

Comment: Got to lay off that RETUN key.  Sorry for that.  Again, thanks for all the responses.  hjpotter kindly provided the links to the documentation; I had thought (obviously incorrectly) that the documentation index located the code I was referring to.  Following Bill Karwin's comment, it seems that

Comment: Sorry again; I'm just too used to hitting RETURN.  Following @Bill Karwin's comment it seems that the statement in the documentation: "A PROCEDURE clause names a procedure that should process the data in the result set."  should read "A PROCEDURE clause names an EXTERNAL procedure.." which would have solved my whole problem.  I was aware of the deprecation of ANALYSE (as stated in my post), but it wasn't at all clear this was a deprecation of the SELECT..PROCEDURE clause as well.  The documentation needs to be clear on this point as well.  Python, etc is not an option in my circumstances.

Comment: Great, I'm glad you got your answer at least. FYI, you can edit your comments (at least for a few minutes) so if you hit return accidentally you can finish your thoughts.